# Getting values from elements added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/R89fn/9/

If any of the text input/Box added are empty then the page must not submit.when I try to retrieve values from the text inputs using their id`s nothing gets retrieved is it possible to retrieve values from elements added dynamically?

```
 $("#submit").click(function (event) {
                var string = "tb";
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    if (document.getElementById(string+1).value=="") {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

The above code is what I am using to get the value from the text fields using there **id**

Comment: setting `string = "tb"` may work, note that `#tb` should be used for `document.querySelector` or some jquery method.

Comment: why not use something like `$('.newTextBox').each(function(index) { })` also as you are getting the div rather than the input, the `.value` won't have a value

Comment: @KingKing No luck I tried $(string+1).val() earlier to get the value that didn`t work  I forgot change back the string value :P sorry about that let me update the question

Comment: @Pete can you explain your method?I`m new to javascript(Don`t know much programming too :P )

Comment: Why the mix of jQuery and plain JS? Pick one.

Comment: it is the [jquery version](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) of your loop - as all your new divs have the class `newTextBox`, you can just select them and then loop through them, instead of trying to get them with their id like you're doing.  I suspect your problem is you are trying to get the value of the input though but your code is trying to get the value of the div (which it won't have one) try: [`$('.newTextBox').children('input').each(function(index) { console.log(this.value); })`](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/R89fn/14/)

Comment: If you're using `jQuery` framework, why not use it all the way? Give my answer a look. It does what you're looking for

Comment: @w0rldart Your new code is good short but after the alert box the page should submit(yes should show page not found or something) but the form remains

Comment: @Pete yes I made a blunder I added those id to the div instead of input tag sorry for that if I were  to add those id to the input tag which method would be fastest

Comment: not sure about performance - I would have thought getting all the elements with the class and looping through would be faster than getting one at a time, but I would just add a class to the input and then use the each loop ([removing the need for the child selector](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/R89fn/16/)) as you're using jQuery, I find it  more readable and easier to maintain, but that's just a personal preference

Comment: @DaveNewton is it bad practice to mix the 2?truth is I don`t know much about them am using w3schools.com and htmldog.com to just write codes

Comment: @AAB well, just remove the `return false`... lol

Comment: @w0rldart remove return false after alert("continue here")?after I remove that form submits after showing which text boxes are empty.

Comment: @AAB It's not *intrinsically* bad, but it's weird in this case, since the equivalent JQ code would be shorter and easier to read. Also be wary of w3schools, it's often bad code (or just wrong).

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks will keep in mind any sources you would recommend to study jquery

Comment: @AAB how about you just play with the code, and try to learn the basics. If you want the form not the be sent if the boxes are empty, then do a `confirm` or `return false` in that `if` syntax. And after the last `alert` if you remove the `return`, it will continue submitting the form. Learn some basics please, and experiment with the code, before just asking.

Comment: @w0rldart  http://jsfiddle.net/KY7nZ/ works!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R89fn/15/

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#b1").click(function () {
        if (count == 5) {
            alert("Maximum Number of Input Boxes Added");
        } else {
            ++count;
            var tb = "tb" + count;
            $('#form').append("<div class=\"newTextBox\" id=" + tb + ">" + 'InputField : <input type="text" name="box[]"></div>');
        }
    });

    $("#b2").click(function () {
        if (count == 0) {
            alert("No More TextBoxes to Remove");
        } else {
            $("#tb" + count).remove();
            --count;
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        var inputBoxes = $('#form').find('input[type="text"]');;

        if (inputBoxes.length < 1) {
            alert('No text inputs to submit');
            return false;
        } else {
            inputBoxes.each(function(i, v) {
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    alert('Input number ' + (i + 1) + ' is empty');
                    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                }
            });

            alert('continue here');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @AAB you don't need `return false` if you already have `event.preventDefault();`... just so you know

Comment: I know I wanted to break the loop the  moment a text field is empty so the return false

Answer (score 2):

I took a look on the code in the JSFiddle. It appears that the input textboxes are not given the intended IDs; the IDs are given to the container div.

The code for the add button should use this,

```
var inputBox = $('<input type="text" id="td1">') //add also the needed attributes
$(containerDiv).append(inputBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="htmlpage.html" method="POST">
<input type="button" id="b1" name="b1" value="Add TextBox" />
<input type="button" id="b2" name="b2" value="Remove TextBox" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<script>
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#b1").click(function() {
            if (count == 5) {
                alert("Maximum Number of Input Boxes Added");
            } else {
                ++count;
                var tb = "tb" + count;
                $(this).before("<div class=\"newTextBox\" id= "+ tb +" >" + 'InputField : <input type="text" name="box[]"></div>');
            }
        });
        $("#b2").click(function() {
            if (count == 0) {
                alert("No More TextBoxes to Remove");
            } else {
                $("#tb" + count).remove();
                --count;
            }
        });
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
            var string = "#texttb";
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            if ($('input[type = text]').val() == "") {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<style>
    .newTextBox
    {
        margin: 5px;z
    }
</style>


Reason:

you had given id to the div element. so its not get retrive. i had updated the answer with the usage of jquery functions and changed your code for this requirement.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your only issue atm is to make sure that the form is not sent if one of the inputs are empty? Seems the solution to your problem is simpler. Simply add required at the end of any input and HTML5 will ensure that the form is not sent if empty. For example:

```
<input type="text" required />
```